# Create Observable which listens for when a function completes

Tags: rxjs, observable

lets say I have a function

```
deleteUser(id){
    if(idExists(id){
       return RxJs.fromPromise(http.request...)
     }else{
       return 'somethingNonAsych'
   }
}
```

I just want to create an Observer like so:

```
deleteUser.subscribe( (complete ) => {
   //user has been deleted somehow
}
```

I don't care if the function called an async method or not, I just want to subscribe to when the actions returns. Im sort of new to Observable creation so looking for some guidance on a good approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript values (string, object, ...) can be converted to observables using Observable.of(...) or Observable.from(...)

```
function idExists(id) { 
    return id === 'exist' ? true : false;
}

function deleteUser(id) {
    if (idExists(id)) {
        return RxJS.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve('delete user'));
    } else {
        return RxJS.Observable.of('user not exist');
    }
}

deleteUser('exist').subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
})

deleteUser('not exist').subscribe((value) => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Observable.defer(...) can be used to create observable lazily.

```
function idExists(id) { 
    return id === 'exist' ? true : false;
}

function deleteUser(id) {
    Observable.defer(() => {
        if (idExists(id)) {
            return RxJS.Observable.fromPromise(Promise.resolve('delete user'));
        } else {
            return RxJS.Observable.of('user not exist');
        }
    }).subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value);
    })
}

deleteUser('exist');
deleteUser('not exist');
```